# How to pick out a particular group of numbers in a string

Tags: regex

I have a string (which is different everytime but follows a similar format):

```
54321.0 67778.0000002 0.3673987009 1 1017.750 88.370 512 7 1 H8711-3040
```

I'm trying to use regular expressions to be able to pick out any one of those entries in my python code, but I'm struggling.

I'm trying

```
testRegex = re.compile(r'\w.+\w')
out = testRegex.search('# 53421.0 67778.0000002 0.3673987009 1 1517.750 88.370 512 7 1 J1745-3040')
print(out.group())
```

But I'm just getting the whole line returned. I can see why it does that but not sure how to just pick out "512" for example (whatever number might be in its place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\b\w(?:\S*\w)?\b', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8uLsxN/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\w` - a word char
- `?:\S*\w)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more non-whitespace chars and then a word char
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BVQujP):

```py
import re
s = '# 53421.0 67778.0000002 0.3673987009 1 1517.750 88.370 512 7 1 J1745-3040'
print( re.findall(r'\b\w(?:\S*\w)?\b', s) )
# => ['53421.0', '67778.0000002', '0.3673987009', '1', '1517.750', '88.370', '512', '7', '1', 'J1745-3040']
```